# Display union statement in columns rather than rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to split results of the union statement in the different columns regarding to attribute 'Label' value, I can't use 'JOIN' statements because I need to get data and counts, for all cases, not only for cases where join conditions is meet.

I have a query like this:

```
Select 
    'Label_1' as Label,
    ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3,
    COUNT (AATR1)
from 
    table
where 
    ATTR4 = '10'
GROUP by  
    'Label_1' as Label, ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3

UNION ALL 

Select 
    'Label_2' as Label,
    ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3,
    COUNT (AATR1)
from 
    table
where 
    ATTR4 = '20'
GROUP by  
    'Label_2' as Label, ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3
```

So I get results like :

```
Label   | ATTR_1| ATTR2| ATTR3| COUNT (AATR1)|
-------------------------------------------
Label_1 | xxxxx  |xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxxx      |
Label_2 |yyyyyy  |yyyyyy|yyyyyy|yyyyyyy      |
```

And I want to get:

```
Label   | ATTR_1_1| ATTR2_1| ATTR3_1| COUNT (AATR1)_1|Label  | ATTR_1_2| ATTR2_2| ATTR3_2| COUNT (AATR1)_2|
Label_1 | xxxxx   |xxxxxx  |xxxxxx  |xxxxxxx         |Label_2|yyyyyy   |yyyyyy  |yyyyyy  |yyyyyyy         |
```

Comment: Ever considered spell-checking?

Comment: Your restriction on using a join sounds like you need to look at an outer join, not a union.

Comment: Why should those two rows be in the same output row? They look to have different attr_1/2/3 values.

Comment: @Alex Poole - not an option, using any join statements, i can't get true count results, because only joined rows will be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two result sets with 1 row each, you can simply do a `CROSS JOIN` to set them side-by-side, like this:

```
select 
    Label_1, ATTR_1_1, ATTR_2_1, ATTR_3_1, AATR1_Count_1, 
    Label_2, ATTR_1_2, ATTR_2_2, ATTR_3_2, AATR1_Count_2
from (
    Select 'Label_1' as Label_1,
           ATTR_1 as ATTR_1_1,
           ATTR2 as ATTR2_1,
           ATTR3 as ATTR3_1,
           COUNT(AATR1) as AATR1_Count_1
    from table
    where ATTR4='10'
    GROUP by ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3
) t1
cross join (
    Select 'Label_2' as Label_2,
           ATTR_1 as ATTR_1_2,
           ATTR2 as ATTR2_2,
           ATTR3 as ATTR3_2,
           COUNT(AATR1) as AATR1_Count_2
    from table
    where ATTR4='20'
    GROUP by ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3
) t2
```

The other option to translate rows into columns (if cross join is not suitable) is to do a pivot query.  Do a google search for "Oracle pivot query example" and you'll see plenty of tactics.

Comment: That only works if there is only one row returned by each subquery. Given the use of the group by, I'm going to go ahead an assume that there could be more than one row returned per attr4.

Comment: @Boneist - that is true, that's why I qualify the answer with the assumption of 1 row per result set. The more general form of translating rows to columns is a pivot query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Label, n, ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3, COUNT(ATTR1) FROM(
    Select 'Label_1' as Label,
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3) n,
            ATTR_1,
            ATTR2,
            ATTR3,
            COUNT (AATR1)
     from table
     where ATTR4='10'
     GROUP by  'Label_1' as Label, ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3
) As firstTable

FULL OUTER JOIN

SELECT Label, m, ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3, COUNT(ATTR1) FROM(
     Select 'Label_2' as Label,
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3) m,
            ATTR_1,
            ATTR2,
            ATTR3,
            COUNT (AATR1)
     from table
     where ATTR4='20'
     GROUP by  'Label_1' as Label, ATTR_1, ATTR2, ATTR3
) AS secondTable

ON firstTable.n = secondTable.m
```

This will give each row a number, then join on the numbers, and so will work regardless of how many rows you have.

Comment: If there's 5 rows returned by the first subquery and only 4 by the second, you'll only get 4 rows returned by the query. You need to change the inner join for a full outer join instead.

Comment: @Boneist you're right, I just thought you might not want to return those rows, not sure why though!

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this give you the accurate counts that you're after?

```
select attr_1,
       attr2,
       attr3,
       nvl(count(case when attr4 = '10' then attr_1 end), 0) label_1_cnt,
       nvl(count(case when attr4 = '20' then attr_1 end), 0) label_2_cnt
from   table1
where  attr4 in ('10', '20')
group by attr_1, attr2, attr3;
```

Plus, there's no need to repeat the attr_1/2/3 columns in each row. Also, it has the advantage of only querying the table once, rather than twice as per your original query.

---

Here's a demo of what the above query would produce with some sample data:

```
with t1 as (select 1 attr_1, 2 attr2, 3 attr3, 10 attr4 from dual union all
            select 1 attr_1, 2 attr2, 3 attr3, 10 attr4 from dual union all
            select 2 attr_1, 3 attr2, 4 attr3, 10 attr4 from dual union all
            select 1 attr_1, 2 attr2, 3 attr3, 20 attr4 from dual union all
            select 2 attr_1, 3 attr2, 4 attr3, 20 attr4 from dual union all
            select 2 attr_1, 3 attr2, 4 attr3, 20 attr4 from dual union all
            select 3 attr_1, 4 attr2, 5 attr3, 20 attr4 from dual union all
            select 2 attr_1, 3 attr2, 4 attr3, 30 attr4 from dual)
select attr_1,
       attr2,
       attr3,
       nvl(count(case when attr4 = '10' then attr_1 end), 0) label_1_cnt,
       nvl(count(case when attr4 = '20' then attr_1 end), 0) label_2_cnt
from   t1
where  attr4 in ('10', '20')
group by attr_1, attr2, attr3
order by 1, 2, 3;

    ATTR_1      ATTR2      ATTR3 LABEL_1_CNT LABEL_2_CNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
         1          2          3           2           1
         2          3          4           1           2
         3          4          5           0           1
```

Your original query would produce the following results with the same sample data:

```
LABEL       ATTR_1      ATTR2      ATTR3 COUNT(ATTR_1)
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------
Label_1          1          2          3             2
Label_1          2          3          4             1
Label_2          1          2          3             1
Label_2          3          4          5             1
Label_2          2          3          4             2
```